# Disassociate android apps in Play Store search

Tags: android, google-play

I apologize in advance if this is not the appropriate forum for this question. I looked at https://android.stackexchange.com/ and it appeared that it definitely wasn't appropriate for that forum.

My company has developed two apps. One for our business users and one for our consumer users. Marketing is very concerned about business users being confused by the offerings and has determined they would like to separate these apps.

We created two google accounts, paid the developer cost twice and used a different (legal) name for our company in one account from the other. Yet when we search for the business app it brings the consumer app back in the results.

We've been over all the information and there are no references between the two in either store listing. Anyone know why they might still be associated and what we can do to prevent it?

(Oddly enough I was able to talk to a google support person but they were not developer support and were unable to help me or direct me to anyone who could)

Comment: Your question is offtopic here too.

Comment: Perhaps they are using heuristics such as similarity of the descriptions?   Or is this more association than you'd find between *competing* apps providing comparable functionality?

Comment: @Luksprog perhaps you could point me to an appropriate forum

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you are using the term "association" here, but it is possible that it will just take a little more time for your changes to take effect. I would give it a few days after making any changes before I start to worry.

Comment: @Tanis.7x - we didn't make a change. The consumer version is a brand new app.  As for association, in that they show up together in a search for one.

Comment: Ah. I think @ChrisStratton is on the right track. For example, if I have two apps called "ACME Consumer" and "ACME Business", then simply searching for "ACME" will likely return both apps. Even if your application names are wildly different, the search results might be including the app category, description, or any of a number of metrics to group the two together.

Comment: @ChrisStratton it's possible but it's only our two apps that show in the results and it's when searching for the name of the business app that it happens.

Comment: What are the package names of both applications? What keystore did your developer use to sign those two applications? The keystore and the package names are what matters to determine ownership of an application. This is what allows a developer to sell an application to someone else who has a different google account.

Comment: They are separate package names and separate keys.

Comment: Are you allowed to reveal the name of those two applications? Personally, I do think this is a programming problem, which is relevant on SO. In my opinion, the way content is indexed is usually a programming problem (And as long as you're not a SEO who's trying to game the system, but someone who's trying to resolve unexpected potentially buggy indexing behavior, that's really what matters here).